# The code works fine outside the function but once inside, it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, replaceall

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']


def strip_punctuation(word):

    for i in punctuation_chars:
        if i in word:
            word = word.replace(i, '')
            return word

print(strip_punctuation('GH.GH,GHGH:GHGH;GHGHG@'))
```

Comment: Your indention of return is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `word` after checking the first item, which means only the first punctuation mark `'` would be stripped. Replace the function with this.

```
def strip_punctuation(word):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        if i in word:
            word = word.replace(i, '')
    return word
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the return is inside of one of the loops, so you only get the first iteration done before printing the returned value. You'd need to put the return at the base of the function - out of the loops.

```
def strip_punctuation(word):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        if i in word:
            word = word.replace(i, '')
    return word
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call return, the function is exited. Therefore, the first time that i is in word and you replace it, you return the word and the function exits. If you were to complete the loop and then return the word, then it should work.

i.e.

```
def strip_punctuation(word):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        if i in word:
           word = word.replace(i, '')
    return word
```